# OpenCV loading video in the memory

Tags: c++, opencv

when using `cv::VideoCapture` to read video from the disk, what does exactly happens?

1. Reading the whole file in the memory then decoding it frame by frame?
2. Fetch frame by frame directly for the disk?

If the second option is the answer, is it possible to do it in the first way?

Comment: The specific answer will probably depend on which backend is being used. However for most scenarios #1 would seem to be a rather silly approach. Why load the whole thing, when you're only processing it sequentially? Imagine how well that would work on a 32bit platform.

Comment: That said, I don't see any provision for this in the OpenCV code, you'll need to write your own decoder for this (e.g. [see this](stackoverflow.com/questions/5237175/process-video-stream-from-memory-buffer) if you're using the ffmpeg backend). What specific scenario are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks... My scenario that I want to process a video while I do not care about how much it takes till it loads completely to the memory. However, after that i want extreme speed so I prefer to read the frames from the memory rather than from the disk frame by frame

Comment: I'd expect that the decoding would be a bigger overhead than the reads. If all the frames will fit in memory decompressed, I'd read the entire video into a vector of Mat objects in first pass and then process that. Probably the simplest way to achieve what you described.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks for help, You may add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish this in Python on Linux, I simply made a copy of the input file to `/dev/shm`, which is a RAM-backed filesystem.

```
tempdir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir='/dev/shm')
copypath = os.path.join(tempdir.name, os.path.basename(args.video))
shutil.copy(args.video, copypath)
args.video = copypath
```

Of course there is the cost of the copy operation as well but it shouldn't be much more than simply reading the entire file (since there is no slow disk that's being written to on the other side of the copy).